# Why does this script for next previous not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this very simple next/previous script and it refuses to work for some reason:

```js
function next(){

  if(document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone.png"){
     document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-2.png";
  }else if(document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-2.png"){
    document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-3.png";
  }else if(document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-3.png"){
    document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-4.png";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone.png"
  }

}

function prev(){

  if(document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone.png"){
     document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-4.png";
  }else if(document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-4.png"){
    document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-3.png";
  }else if(document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-3.png"){
    document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone-2.png";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("im").src = "img/phone.png"
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="prev" onclick="prev()"></div>

<div class="image">
  <img id="im" src="img/phone.png">
</div>

<div class="next" onclick="next()"></div>
```

I've been trying to fix it for an hour with no luck. And If I remove all the arguments and leave only two, it works!

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ruskn6z/)

Comment: in your `if` statements you need to use the equals equalator ==, not =

Comment: Also, have a look at [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: Using only = means to check if it's true or false, so there's no problem there. And I tried to switch it still does not work

Comment: First if statement will be true as you are doing assignment not a truth/false check

Comment: Yeah, no, that's not how the operators work. A single `=` is the assignment operator - whatever is on the right gets assigned to whatever is on the left. The equality operator is `==`. For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Answer (score 1):

```js
let img = document.getElementById("im");

function next(){
  if(img.src == "img/phone.png"){
     img.src = "img/phone-2.png";
  }else if(img.src == "img/phone-2.png"){
    img.src = "img/phone-3.png";
  }else if(img.src == "img/phone-3.png"){
    img.src = "img/phone-4.png";
  }else{
    img.src = "img/phone.png"
  }
}

function prev(){
  if(img.src == "img/phone.png"){
     img.src = "img/phone-4.png";
  }else if(img.src == "img/phone-4.png"){
    img.src = "img/phone-3.png";
  }else if(img.src == "img/phone-3.png"){
    img.src = "img/phone-2.png";
  }else{
    img.src = "img/phone.png"
  }
}
```

`=` vs `==`

```js
var a = 1;

if( a == 2 ){
  console.log(" a=1 ") //this won't show
}

if( a = 2 ){
  console.log(" a=2 ") //this will show 
}

// a = 2 is an assignment and always returns `true`
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, is there something I'm missing maybe?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle maybe? So I can see where I'm going wrong!

Comment: @Information_For_Sell would it  always  to  the `else{..}` block?

Comment: It's basically a sort of slider, but I need it in this way so I can add more arguments for each click. I tried your way and I know it makes sense code-wise, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe if you provide a jsfiddle, I can fix my code according to it

Comment: @Information_For_Sell fixed the issue in that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fy269gxk/), check the edit also

Comment: With some placeholder images: https://jsfiddle.net/z432xbsd/1/